# Динамический JS

Tags: javascript

Помогите начинающему программисту. Необходимо Сделать на чистом JS. При изменении числа квадрат должен менять цвет. И еще не могу разобраться как сделать ассоциативный массив в этом коде.

```js
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
var color = ["#00FF00", "#ADFF2F", "#00FA9A", "#228B22", "#808000", "#8FBC8F", "#20B2AA", "#008080", "#00BFFF",
  "#00008B", "#FF00FA", "#4B0082", "#8B4513", "#FF00FF", "#800000", "#FF0000"
]

var param = ["number > 1 && number < 6",
  "number > 7 && number < 12",
  "number > 13 && number < 18",
  "number > 19 && number < 24",
  "number > 25 && number < 30",
  "number > 31 && number < 36",
  "number > 37 && number < 42",
  "number > 43 && number < 48",
  "number > 49 && number < 54",
  "number > 55 && number < 60",
  "number > 61 && number < 66",
  "number > 67 && number < 72",
  "number > 73 && number < 78",
  "number > 79 && number < 84",
  "number > 85 && number < 90",
  "number > 90"
]

document.getElementById("block").innerHTML = number;

var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.className = "part";
elem.style.width = "100px";
elem.style.height = "100px";
elem.style.backgroundColor = "black";
document.getElementById("block").appendChild(elem);
console.log(elem);
```

```html
<p id="block">
</p>
```

Comment: Вам нужен рандомный цвет при каждом значении, либо же с подобной сортировкой, что Вы указали?

Comment: С подобранной сортировкой

Comment: На сколько вижу - Вам уже дали ответ, который Вы приняли.

Comment: Мне дали ответ в котором берется рандомное число из длинны массива и к нему привязывается цвет. Мне же необходимо не к конкретному числу а в диапазоне. Например от 1 до 10 - один цвет, от 11 до 21 - другой цвет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Генерация, случайного цвета в зависимости от массива `color`. Для данной задачи ассоциативный массив не нужен. В js как таковых ассоциативных массивов нет. Здесь всё используется с помощью объектов. Пример:

```
var params = {
   "item": {
       "id" : 1,
       "name": 'Hello'
   },
   "color": "#000"
}
```

Ниже решение Вашей задачи.

```js
var color = ["#00FF00", "#ADFF2F","#00FA9A","#228B22","#808000","#8FBC8F","#20B2AA","#008080","#00BFFF",
    "#00008B","#FF00FA","#4B0082","#8B4513","#FF00FF","#800000","#FF0000"
]

document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(color.length));;
    document.getElementById("block").innerHTML = number;

    var elem = document.createElement('div');
        elem.className="part";
        elem.style.width = "100px";
        elem.style.height = "100px";
        elem.style.backgroundColor = color[number];
        document.getElementById("block").appendChild(elem);
    });
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">generate</button>

<div id="block">

</div>
```

Comment: Цвет фигуры должен меняться в зависимости от диапазона, а не от фиксированного числа.
Если цифра в диапазоне от 1 до 10 - один цвет
если от 11 до 21 - другой цвет.

Answer (score -1):

А можно чуть больше инфы:
Что это за массив param?
Цвет зависит от значения числа? Например, желтый включается при значениях от 10 до 20, черный - 21...31 и т.д. или как?
и зачем тут ассоциативный массив в контексте задачи? Потому что его можно сделать по разному (вернее, добавлять и брать оттуда элементы можно по-разному)